# How to go about solving $((1+iz)/(1-iz))^4 = 1/2 + i\sqrt3/2$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have problem solving this equation:
$$
 \left(\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}\right)^4 = \frac12 + i {\sqrt{3}\over 2}
$$
I know how to solve equations that are like:
$$
 w^4 = \frac12 + i {\sqrt{3}\over 2}
$$
And I have solved it to:
$$
    w = \cos(-\frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{\pi k}{2})) + i\sin(-\frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{\pi k}{2}))
$$
But now is:
$$
    w = \frac{1+iz}{1-iz}
$$
How does one get the complex z? Or am I solving it wrong?

Comment: Please add appropriate _MathJax_ code so your question is understandable.

Comment: @ParthKohli: Yeah, I'm trying to get it to work. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$w=\frac{1+\mathrm iz}{1-\mathrm iz}\iff z=\mathrm i\cdot\frac{1-w}{1+w}$$
**Edit:** On the road are the identities $(1-\mathrm iz)\cdot w=1+\mathrm iz$ and $1-w=-\mathrm i\cdot(1+w)\cdot z$.

Comment: What are the steps you are taking in order to get z? I've struggled around a bit with the conjugate, but that gets me to z squared.

Comment: See Edit. (No conjugate at all in the picture.)

Comment: @JulianAssange : The "steps" are made explicit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$
w=\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}
$$
First, multiply both sides by $1-iz$:
$$
w(1-iz) = 1+iz
$$
Expand the left side:
$$
w-wiz = 1+iz
$$
Put all terms involving $z$ on one side and those not involving $z$ on the other side:
$$
w-1=iz+wiz
$$
Factor
$$
w-1 = iz(1+w)
$$
Divide both sides by $i(1+w)$:
$$
z= \frac{w-1}{i(w+1)}
$$
Multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate, $-i$:
$$
z = -i\frac{w-1}{w+1} = i\frac{1-w}{1+w}.
$$